# Datables Rowspan in <tbody>: Cannot read property 'className' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I'm using JQuery and DataTable plugin with my tables. So, I need use rowspan in the body of my tables, but a error message is displayed  in the console of the chrome:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of undefined

I read about the fakeRowspan plugin, but I don't know how use it.

See my fiddle with the problem:
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mayconfsbrito/9mkHz/6/)

JQuery code for the dataTable initialization:

```
$('.table').dataTable({
    "sScrollY": "400px",
        "sScrollX": "100%",
        "bPaginate": $('.table').hasClass('paginacao'), //Dropdown de número de linhas paginadas
        "bFilter": true, //Filtro de busca da tabela
        "bSort": true, //Ordenação das colunas da tabela
        "bInfo": true,
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "oLanguage": {
            "sUrl": "/fwsibe/assets/bootstrap/temas/AdminLTE/js/plugins/datatables/dataTables.pt-br.txt"
        }
});
```

Comment: Tried this, but I don't get any errors... which version of jquery and jquery datatable are you using?

Comment: So the plugin has a bug. Report it to the developer.

Comment: I'm using jquery-2.1.0 and jquery.datatables-1.9.4.

Comment: I don't believe which be a plugin problem, because this is a so basic functionality, and must there exists various tables with this.